# ion-toggle 2 way binding between components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm building settings out in my app, and our Settings page has multiple categories for settings. In order to manage this, my Settings page flows as follows: `SettingsPage <uses> ProfileSettingsComponent <uses> SettingsComponent[]`. I'm having issues with the child and grandchildren component pieces.

I'm trying to pass in a piece of a settings object into `SettingsComponent` and have it bind back to the parent. Right now, if I pass in the setting property, all I get back is the value, not the name of the property, nor does the property get updated on the parent.

Let's get to some code...

`ProfileSettingsComponent`

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { SettingsService } from "../../services/settings.service";
import { SettingsKeys } from "../../constants/settings.constants";

@Component({
    selector: "profile-settings",
    template: "profile-settings.component.html",
})
export class ProfileSettingsComponent implements OnInit {

    public settings: ProfileSettings;

    constructor(private _settings: SettingsService) { }

    public ngOnInit() {
         this.settings = new ProfileSettings(settings[SettingsKeys.Profile] || {})) // returns {email:false, name:false}, etc.
            .then(() => console.log(this.profile, this.settings));
    }

    public updateSettings(e) {
        console.log('Settings.Profile', this.settings); // Eventually persist this back to settings once this.settings actually updates from the child component
    }
```

`profile-settings.component.html`

```html
<div class="profile-settings" padding>
    <ion-list *ngIf="settings">
        <setting label="Email" [(setting)]="settings.email" (toggled)="updateSettings($event)"></setting>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

`setting.component.ts`

```ts
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "setting",
    templateUrl: "setting.component.html"
})
export class SettingComponent {

    @Input() public label: string;
    @Input() public setting: any;
    @Output() public toggled: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor() { }

    public toggle(e) {
        this.toggled.emit(this.setting);
    }

}
```

`setting.component.html`

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>
        <h2>{{label}}</h2>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="setting" (ngModelChange)="toggle($event)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

What seemed like the most trivial thing to do in Angular 1 -- update a parent property injected into a child component -- is extremely difficult. Does anyone have the right direction for me to follow to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your code correct you are passing `settings.email` to your child component which is either `true` or `false`. Which is correct to make you ngModel work in your child component but on ngModelChange you are just passing `this.setting` back to your parent component which can again only be `true` or `false` so the behaviour you are describing is expected.

If you want to know which setting was changed you need to pass more information to your child component e.g.:

```
{ id: 1, email: false }
```

And in your child component you initialize your ngModel in `ngOnInit` like this:

```
this.myNgModel = setting.email
```

And in your `toggle` method you can do something like that:

```
this.toggle.emit({ id: setting.id, email: this.myNgModel });
```

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to...I was hoping I wasn't just passing in the value of the property, but the actual reference.

I can modify the component to be something like `<setting id="email" [(setting)]="settings.email" label="Who cares..."></setting>`

Comment: I don't think that will actually help your use case, your child component needs to know which setting it is representing, so you need to pass that info down to it: `<setting [setting]="{ settingId: "email", status: setting.email }"></setting>`, something like that.

Comment: I gotcha. It's not ideal -- I'd still like to be able to actually pass the reference in, but I guess I can't

Comment: Being able to do a two-way binding across components would result in a total chaos, thats why component interaction either happens through input properties and output events or via an injectable class.